# Eclipse plugin: How to extend perspective with View, that is implemented by external plugin

Tags: node.js, view, eclipse-plugin, perspective, plugin.xml

There is an Eclipse plugin, that defines Node perspective in [plugin.xml file](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/plugin.xml).

I'd like to add default View to this perspective, that is implemented by [Markdown Editor](http://www.winterwell.com/software/markdown-editor.php).
Namely Markdown HTML preview.

Will Eclipse behave nicely if user don't install Markdown plugin, that will be referenced?

I would also like to add Eclipse standard Error Log (for user to see if an error happened).

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "add default view to this perspective?" You wish to modify the source code to add this view to the Node perspective? Or you wish to add a plugin that will add this view to the perspective using a perspective extension?

To log, you should use the `StatusManager`. See http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_statushandling.htm for how to use this properly.

Comment: Every time me (or every user) install Nodeclipse in new Eclipse, I/user need to go to Window->Show view-> other ... and select Markdown HTML preview. I want to save those 5 second for every user.

Comment: Without modifying the source code, you would do this using a [perspective extension](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html)